# What's the difference between the Norwegian fjord and the Scottish sea loch?

Tags: terminology, sea, scotland, norway

I want to know the major differences between these two systems.

Comment: No one pines for sea lochs....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, just the name.  *Fjord* is of Norse origin, *loch* of Gaelic.

They are the same feature, formed when glaciers debouch into the sea.

In both countries, you'll find varying scales, from a few hundred metres in width to several kilometres.

Comment: TIL the word debouch: emerge from a narrow area.  Of French origin.

Comment: This is wrong. Maybe the Scottish lochs were made by glaciers, but the fjords were made by Slartibartfast. He even won an award for them.

Comment: `:-)` @StrongBad

Answer (score 0):

Geologically significantly different.  Fjords are flooded glacial valleys, and usually have very steep sides. Often the fjord itself is deeper than the ocean beyond it's mouth.  Many have very inaccessible shorelines except at the extreme ends.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fjord

Loch is used both for lake, and for a confined or protected sea inlet.

Firth is another term, tends to refer to a more open body of water.  The use of the terms is not consistent.

Comment: Do you know a *sea loch* that isn't a *flooded glacial valley*?  Even Loch Linnhe falls into that category, although its sides are much gentler than many, due to the Great Glen Fault.